# Programmatically check the number of cores application is using

Tags: c++, multicore

Is there a way to **programmatically** check how many cores a C++ application is using?

I am looking for `Windows/Linux` solution but of course  platform independent solution would be preferable, I guess its asking for too much.

Comment: I'd say it's pretty hard to determine that. You can determine the load on different cores, and you can determine how many threads a particular process is using, and how much of the total CPU time it's using, but "how many cores are being used by this process at precisely this point in time", I don't think is available in any direct way.

Comment: Ypu - like @MatsPetersson says, any such information, even if avaialble, would be stale by the time you got it.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to know how many cores a application uses. But you can **guess** it by the number of threads it has.

For windows:

You're going to want to use the [Tool Help Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681926%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) as microsoft calls it. More specifically you're going to want to take a look at the [Traversing the Thread List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686852%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) example which can get you the number of threads a application has.

Microsoft really loves to make their examples as ugly as one could possibly make them, so heres a prettified version I came up with, you feed it a PID and it lists all the threads associated with it:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <cstdio>

bool list(unsigned int PID);

int main(void)
{
    list(5532);
    list(GetCurrentProcessId());

    return 0;
}

bool list(unsigned int PID)
{
    HANDLE thread_snap = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    THREADENTRY32 te32;

    // Take a snapshot of all running threads
    thread_snap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD, 0);
    if (thread_snap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) return false;

    // Fill in the size of the structure before using it.
    te32.dwSize = (DWORD)sizeof(THREADENTRY32);

    // Retrieve information about the first thread, and exit if unsuccessful
    if (!Thread32First(thread_snap, &te32))
    {
        CloseHandle(thread_snap);
        return false;
    }

    // Now walk the thread list of the system, and display information about each thread associated with the specified process
    printf("Printing threads for PID %u\n", PID); 
    do
    {
        if (te32.th32OwnerProcessID == PID)
        {
            printf( "THREAD ID = 0x%08X with base priority %u and delta priority %u\n", (unsigned int)te32.th32ThreadID, (unsigned int)te32.tpBasePri, (unsigned int)te32.tpDeltaPri);
        }
    }
    while (Thread32Next(thread_snap, &te32));
    printf("Done printing threads for PID %u\n\n", PID);

    //  Don't forget to clean up the snapshot object.
    CloseHandle(thread_snap);

    return true;
}
```

Input:

`5532` (steam's service process ID for me), `GetCurrentProcessId()`

Output:

```
Printing threads for PID 5532
THREAD ID = 0x00000BCC with base priority 8 and delta priority 0
THREAD ID = 0x0000041C with base priority 8 and delta priority 0
THREAD ID = 0x00001924 with base priority 8 and delta priority 0
THREAD ID = 0x00000C9C with base priority 8 and delta priority 0
Done printing threads for PID 5532

Printing threads for PID 9836
THREAD ID = 0x000000FC with base priority 8 and delta priority 0
Done printing threads for PID 9836
```

---

You can assume that if a application uses more threads than the number of cores the cpu has it probably uses all of them and if it uses less, it probably uses x number of cores, where x is the number of threads.

If you want to go even further, you can get the CPU usage for each thread to make a better **approximation** of how many cores it uses.

---

Another approach that I'm not entirely sure would work is to take the CPU usage of all the threads of a application and add them up (in percentage), take the number of cores the system has, raise that number to the power of -1 and multiply it with 100 (`x^-1*100`) where x is the number of cores, and then divide the percentage of CPU usage of all threads to the percentage of how much a core can handle to approximate how many cores it uses.

For example:

Given 4 cores and a application with 4 threads, 2 of each are at 25% CPU usage and other 2 at 11% each.

You could assume that it uses:

(25+25+11+11)/((4^-1)*100) = 2.88 cores

The problem:

Its possible that not all cores are clocked at same speed. In which case its not going to work as intended.

---

If you're using c++11 you can find out the number of cores the system has with `std::thread::hardware_concurrency()`.

Alternatively you can also [traverse the process list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686701%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and get the number of threads a process has from there, but it doesn't have advanced info about each thread like traversing the threads has.

Comment: I like the second approach better, it will need testing, thanks for the quick and informative reply

Comment: @makc No problem, hope it helped. If you're going to use the formula I came up with let me know how the tests go, I'd also love to know if you come up with a fix for the possibility that the cores aren't clocked at same speed. Its rare but its still a possibility.

Comment: when there will be something running I'll post here.your answer isn't accepted yet since I am still hoping some one will have a more definite solution, you already got mine +1 :)

Answer (score 3):

Going to make a second answer here because the last one is already long enough and this answer is going to go in a slightly different direction.

After further research I determined that there actually is a way to figure out precisely what core each thread is/can running/run on. The code I came up with uses heavily windows specific libraries, but there surely are linux equivalent functions.

More specifically its using `wbemuuid.lib`, `comdef.h` and `Wbemidl.h`.

---

***The code:***

```
#define _WIN32_DCOM

#include <iostream>
#include <comdef.h>
#include <Wbemidl.h>
#include <cstdarg>
#include <string>

#pragma comment(lib, "wbemuuid.lib")

using namespace std;

DWORD affinity(unsigned int ID)
{
    HANDLE threadh = OpenThread(THREAD_SET_INFORMATION | THREAD_QUERY_INFORMATION, FALSE, ID);

    DWORD mask = 1;
    DWORD old = 0;

    while (mask)
    {
        old = SetThreadAffinityMask(threadh, mask);
        if (old)
        {
            SetThreadAffinityMask(threadh, old);
            return old;
        }
        else
        {
            if (GetLastError() != ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER) return 0;
        }
        mask <<= 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

HRESULT connect(IWbemLocator** pLoc, IWbemServices** pSvc)
{
    HRESULT hres;

    hres = CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED); 
    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Failed to initialize COM library. Error code = 0x" << hex << hres << endl;
        return hres;
    }

    hres = CoInitializeSecurity(NULL, -1, NULL, NULL, RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT, RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, NULL, EOAC_NONE, NULL);
    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Failed to initialize security. Error code = 0x" << hex << hres << endl;
        CoUninitialize();
        return hres;
    }

    hres = CoCreateInstance( CLSID_WbemLocator, 0, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IWbemLocator, (LPVOID*)&(*pLoc));
    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Failed to create IWbemLocator object." << " Error code = 0x" << hex << hres << endl;
        CoUninitialize();
        return hres;
    }

    hres = (*pLoc)->ConnectServer(_bstr_t(L"ROOT\\CIMV2"), NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, 0, &(*pSvc));
    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Could not connect. Error code = 0x" << hex << hres << endl;
        (*pLoc)->Release(); 
        CoUninitialize();
        return hres;
    }

    hres = CoSetProxyBlanket((*pSvc), RPC_C_AUTHN_WINNT, RPC_C_AUTHZ_NONE, NULL, RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CALL, RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, NULL, EOAC_NONE);

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Could not set proxy blanket. Error code = 0x" << hex << hres << endl;
        (*pSvc)->Release();
        (*pLoc)->Release();     
        CoUninitialize();
        return hres;
    }

    return hres;
}

HRESULT query(IWbemLocator** pLoc, IWbemServices** pSvc, IEnumWbemClassObject** pEnum, const char* qry)
{
    HRESULT hres;

    hres = (*pSvc)->ExecQuery(bstr_t("WQL"), bstr_t(qry), WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY, NULL, &(*pEnum));

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Query for operating system name failed." << " Error code = 0x" << hex << hres << endl;
        (*pSvc)->Release();
        (*pLoc)->Release();
        CoUninitialize();
        return 1;
    }

    return hres;
}

HRESULT parse(IWbemLocator** pLoc, IWbemServices** pSvc, IEnumWbemClassObject** pEnum, IWbemClassObject** pCls, size_t n_args, ...)
{
    HRESULT hres;

    ULONG uReturn = 0;

    while (pEnum)
    {
        hres = (*pEnum)->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, &(*pCls), &uReturn);

        if (0 == uReturn)
        {
            break;
        }

        VARIANT vtProp;

        va_list vl;
        va_start(vl, n_args);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < n_args; i++)
        {
            const char* name = va_arg(vl, const char*);

            int wchars_num =  MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, name, -1, NULL, 0);
            wchar_t* wname = new wchar_t[wchars_num];
            MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8 , 0, name, -1, wname, wchars_num);

            hres = (*pCls)->Get(wname, 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
            wcout << wname << " : " << std::to_wstring((size_t)vtProp.bstrVal) << " : " << affinity((DWORD)vtProp.bstrVal) << endl;

            delete[] wname;
        }
        va_end(vl);

        VariantClear(&vtProp);
    }

    return hres;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    string qry = "SELECT * FROM Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Thread WHERE IDProcess = 7424";

    HRESULT hres;

    IWbemLocator* pLoc = NULL;
    IWbemServices* pSvc = NULL;

    IEnumWbemClassObject* pEnum = NULL;

    IWbemClassObject* pCls = NULL;

    hres = connect(&pLoc, &pSvc);
    if (FAILED(hres)) return 1;

    hres = query(&pLoc, &pSvc, &pEnum, qry.c_str());
    if (FAILED(hres)) return 1;

    hres = parse(&pLoc, &pSvc, &pEnum, &pCls, 1, "IDThread");
    if (FAILED(hres)) return 1;

    pSvc->Release();
    pLoc->Release();
    pEnum->Release();
    pCls->Release();
    CoUninitialize();

    return 0;   
}
```

***Outputs when Prime95 is stopped:***

```
IDThread : 9072 : 15
IDThread : 7052 : 15
```

***Outputs when Prime95 is running with 4 worker threads:***

```
IDThread : 9072 : 15
IDThread : 7052 : 15
IDThread : 5600 : 1
IDThread : 5888 : 2
IDThread : 2888 : 4
IDThread : 9348 : 8

PercentProcessorTime : 0
PercentProcessorTime : 0
PercentProcessorTime : 70
PercentProcessorTime : 83
PercentProcessorTime : 80
PercentProcessorTime : 75
```

***Outputs when Prime95 is running with 2 worker threads:***

```
IDThread : 9072 : 15
IDThread : 7052 : 15
IDThread : 2352 : 15
IDThread : 8396 : 15
```

---

***Explanation:***

To explain the code a little bit:

- `7424` is the PID of Prime95.
- `SELECT * FROM Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Thread WHERE IDProcess = 7424` is the query I'm using to list all threads related to the specific PID. You can find a list of all the info you can get from `Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Thread` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394279%28VS.85%29.aspx). All you have to do is switch the argument given to `parse()` from `ThreadID` to lets say `PercentProcessorTime` for instance and its going to output the CPU usage percentage.
- The code is very ugly and possibly unsafe, its also a heavily modified version of [Example: Getting WMI Data from the Local Computer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa390423%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from MSDN.

---

***Affinity:***

The function `affinity()` sets the thread affinity to a new one to get the old one and then sets it back to the old one. Now, I'm unsure how to get the actual core number from affinity, what I know is that if its for example `1` it runs on core number 1, if its `2` it runs of core number 2, if its `7` it runs on cores 4 and 3 or something along those lines. I have yet to fully figure it out.

---

***Porting it to linux:***

On linux its all a bit easier, for instance getting the core can be done with something like [`sched_getcpu`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sched_getcpu.3.html)/[`sched_getaffinity`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sched_setaffinity). With a bit of googling I'm sure you can find a method to list all threads associated with a process too.